# CSS Minimize Whitespace on Window Size Change Instead of Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid, removing-whitespace

I have a web page that is 65% css grid and 35% white space.  When you minimize the page a little / make it smaller, it maintains those percentages.  Rather than strictly adhering to those percentages, I want the page to only take away white space when possible.  How do I do that?

Here is the code that currently sets the width of the css grid:

```
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    padding-right: 1px;
    float: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    width: 65%;
    }
```

Comment: If you specify a percentage it will use that. It sounds to me as though you want a fixed width or at least a `min-width`

Comment: Thanks, since I'm new around here and I added a snippet, can you remove the down vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post some code to explain further what you are trying to achieve

As I interpreted your question at the moment you need to add a fixed size to the css-grid (or it's container).

```
<div class="cssgrid">

.cssgrid {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

If that's not what you want you may need a mediaquery which hides/shows the white space after a certain resolution is reached

Comment: Thanks, I think the media query is probably the best solution, but the fixed height /width solution will be quicker.  I will see if I can get away with fixed height/width.